# Removing directories with spaces in their directory paths

Tags: filenames, quoting, rm

I'm on macOS.  I have many directories at paths that looks like this:

```
./FirstName SecondName/A Multi Word Title/Contents/Index/files
```

I want to remove ALL the `Index` directories and their contents.  I tried escaping the spaces with `\` but that didn't work.  If necessary I'm willing to make two passes, removing the files and then removing the directory.

Comment: I want to remove the directories and their contents but they are at the end of long strings with spaces.  I tried using the rm command, attempting to escape the spaces but I get a No such file error message.  If I manually type in the string, escaping the spaces, it works but it is a lot faster to just go into finder and delete them.  I'm trying to use something like "find . -name index" and use that to remove the directories and their contents by piping it to "xargs rm."

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to remove all of them, you would use shell filename patterns:

```bash
rm -i -v -r ./*/*/Contents/Index
```

Check the `rm` man page for the meaning of the options.

Answer (score 1):

To search for directories called `Index` in or below the current directory, and then to delete these, you would use `find` like so:

```bash
find . -depth -name Index -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

This does a depth-first search for the specific directories you are interested in and invokes `rm -r` on each of them in turn.  We need to do a depth-first search (with `-depth`) as we might otherwise remove directories that haven't yet been visited by `find`, which would generate errors.

Use `-path '*/Contents/Index'` in place of the `-name` test if you need the `Index` directory to be a child directory of a `Contents` directory.

Using the `zsh` shell, or the `bash` shell with its `globstar` shell option set, you may also be able to use

```bash
rm -r ./**/Index/
```

or

```bash
rm -r ./**/Contents/Index/
```

This would call `rm -r` with a list of pathnames of directories called `Index` (assuming all the parts of the directory path are non-hidden, and assuming you're ok with also deleting directories symbolically linked via the name `Index`, and assuming the list of matching pathnames is not thousands of entries long). The trailing slash ensures that only directories are affected.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution from another source and it worked.

```
find . -name directory* -print0 | xargs -0 rm -R
```

Comment: Note that the unquoted pattern `directory*` would be expanded before the `find` utility is called, and if it expands to more than one name, it would generate an error. In the `zsh` shell, it would generate an error by default if the pattern _isn't_ matching anything.  Also note that you need to attribute sources if you are copying code from elsewhere.